# Is it possible to compress 8 numbers (0-3) to less than two bytes?

Tags: c#, math, encoding, compression, encode

Given an array of 8 numbers ranging between 0-3, is it possible to compress that to be less than 2 bytes?

ie:

int[] array = { 3,2,0,0,1,0,2,2 }

By combining 3,2,0,0 together and 1,0,2,2 together I can create the bytes 11100000 (224) and 01001010 (74) but I'm curious if its possible any other way to reduce this to less than 2 bytes via encoding perhaps?

Comment: it would be great if you add some samples, or more details about inputs and outputs]

Comment: There are 4 possible values per number and 8 numbers.  That means 4^8 or 2^16 different combinations.  Given no other constraints on the numbers, that suggests that you will need 16 bits or 2 bytes.

Comment: A number from 0-3 takes 2 binary bits to store so 8 of them is 16 bits (i.e. 2 bytes)

Comment: I doubt you can make it less than 2 bytes because then you would need to encode additional information into the bits to indicate when 1 number stops and the next one starts.

Comment: Representing the input perfectly, no, there is no way. Using a run-style encoding technique, you could potentially get it down to a minimum of 5 bits using the pattern of 2 bits for number followed by 3 bits for count (3 bits since the maximum length of numbers is 8). If the list of numbers is 8 identical numbers (e.g. `{ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 }`), then it could be stored in binary as `00111`, with the first two bits representing the number `0` and the other three bits representing the length of the run `8` (on a range of `{1,8}`, since storing a run length of `0` is nonsensical).

Comment: Of course, using the run-style encoding, you could also get a worst-case scenario of 5 x 8 bits, or 40 bits (5 bytes), if there are no runs in the input array (e.g. `{ 0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3 }`). On that note, anything more than three runs in an array (15 bits) will result in a less efficient method to store data than a direct representation, so I wouldn't recommend it unless the majority of your arrays will be guaranteed to have three or fewer runs.

Comment: @Abion47 Thank you for your answer, that is very helpful!  Does it perhaps change anything if the range of the numbers are extended to 0-15?

Comment: The real question is why are you trying to do this.  If you have a file whose contents you are trying to compress, you're going to have to do a lot of work to do better than just zipping the file and moving on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

8 numbers with 4 choices each will allow 4<sup>8</sup>=2<sup>(8⋅2)</sup> different combinations, so you need to have two bytes to encode all of them.

Depending on the details of your input, it *may* be possible to find an ecoding where *typical* input gets encoded to less than two bytes. But you pay for this by needing more than two bytes for atypical input.